# how to use myTween.reverse(); using as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have used this code:

```
TweenMax.to(myButton, 2, {scaleX:1.5, scaleY:1.5, ease:Elastic.easeOut});
```

to let an object spread out I have the code from http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/ but I want that if I click the object again it goes reverse I schould do this:

```
var myTween:TweenMax = new TweenMax(movieclip1, 3, {y:200, repeat:2,  repeatDelay:1, onComplete:myFunction});

movieclip1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reverse); // Add the button click

function reverse(e:MouseEvent):void {

TweenMax.reverse();}
```

but I get an error

Answer (score 0):

You have to call it on a tween instance -

> myTween.reverse();

Comment: thanks for the reply but I get an error that it can't find myFunction

Comment: onComplete:myFunction - what is that doing there? If you don't need the onComplete event, remove it.